# User row not deleting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get it so once user has clicked on a selected check box and then the delete button it will remove that row.

I am unable to get it to delete the users row that has been chosen.

My delete function on users is not working with the model.

**Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    public function deleteUser($user_id) {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->delete('user');
    }

    public function getUsers() {
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->select('date_added');
        $this->db->select('status');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->limit(20);
        $this->db->order_by('username', 'asc');
        $query_user = $this->db->get();
        if ($query_user->num_rows) {
            return $query_user->result_array();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends MX_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load('admin/user/users', 'english');
        $this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');
        if ($this->session->userdata('isLogged')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            redirect('admin');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));
        $this->getList();
    }

    public function add() {

    }

    public function edit() {

    }

    public function delete() {

        if ($this->input->post('selected') == TRUE) {

            $this->users_model->deleteUser($user_id);

            redirect('users/users');

        } else {

            $this->getList();

        }
    }

    private function getList() {

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

        // Get Bread Crumbs

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>' .' '.  $this->lang->line('text_home'),
            'href' => site_url('admin/dashboard')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
            'href'      => site_url('admin/users')
        );

        // Get DB Results

        $data['users'] = array();

        $results = $this->users_model->getUsers();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['users'][] = array(
                'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                'username' => $result['username'],
                'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                'status' => ($result['status'] ? $this->lang->line('text_enabled') : $this->lang->line('text_disabled')),
                'edit' => site_url('admin/users/edit/' . $result['user_id']),
                'delete' => site_url('admin/users/delete/' . $result['user_id'])
            );
        }

        // Set Data

        $data['text_confirm'] = $this->lang->line('text_confirm');

        $data['column_username'] = $this->lang->line('column_username');
        $data['column_status'] = $this->lang->line('column_status');
        $data['column_date_added'] = $this->lang->line('column_date_added');
        $data['column_action'] = $this->lang->line('column_action');

        if (trim($this->input->post('selected'))) {
            $data['selected'] = (array)$this->input->post('selected');
        } else {
            $data['selected'] = array();
        }

        return $this->load->view('user/users', $data);

    }

}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');?><?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/column_left/index');?>

<div id="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h1><?php echo $heading_title;?></h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);" /></td>
        <td><b><a>User ID<a></b></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_username;?><a></b></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_status;?><a></b></td>
        <td><b><a><?php echo $column_date_added;?></a></b></td>
        <td class="text-right"><b><?php echo $column_action;?></b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($users) { ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center"><?php if (in_array($user['user_id'], $selected)) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" /> 
<?php } ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['user_id'];?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['status']; ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo $user['date_added']; ?></td>
<td class="text-right">
<a href="<?php echo $user['edit']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<a href="<?php echo $user['delete']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('Are You Sure You Wish To Delete This User?') ? $('#form-user').submit() : false;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- . Table Responsive -->
</div><!-- . Panel Panel-Body -->
</div><!--  . Panel Panel-Default -->
</div><!-- . Columns -->
</div><!-- . Row -->
</div><!-- . Container-fluid-->
</div><!-- #Content -->

<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');?>
```

Comment: Try to echo $user_id in model to check its value (my guess: it is empty/undefined). If you pass post value (user id for deletion) via link -> you need url segment of it: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Is it safe to use uri segment I can remove it that way fine or is it best and a better practice to use variable.

Comment: There is no difference from security point -> all POST data are very visible, and easy accessible, even if they aren't visible to user in URL... So, you just have to check admin privileges for admin functions, so ordinary user can't type http://yoursiteurl.com/admin/delete/some_user_id in address bar and delete user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't send a parameter of `$user_id`

```
public function delete() { // here you need to send a parameter $user_id ex. delete($user_id)

        if ($this->input->post('selected') == TRUE) {

            $this->users_model->deleteUser($user_id);

            redirect('users/users');

        } else {

            $this->getList();

        }
    }
```